# An error "regularMarketOpen" while downloading data from Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I'm trying to download data from Yahoo Finance using yfinance package. I use a code below:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

fang = ['FB','AMZN','NFLX','GOOG']
tickers = [yf.Ticker(ticker) for ticker in fang]
dfs = [] # list for each ticker's dataframe
for ticker in tickers:
    # get each financial statement
    pnl = ticker.financials
    bs = ticker.balancesheet
    cf = ticker.cashflow

    # concatenate into one dataframe
    fs = pd.concat([pnl, bs, cf])

    # make dataframe format nicer
    # Swap dates and columns
    data = fs.T
    # reset index (date) into a column
    data = data.reset_index()
    # Rename old index from '' to Date
    data.columns = ['Date', *data.columns[1:]]
    # Add ticker to dataframe
    data['Ticker'] = ticker.ticker
    dfs.append(data)
data.iloc[:,:3]# for display purposes
```

But I have an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 8>()
      7 dfs = [] # list for each ticker's dataframe
      8 for ticker in tickers:
      9     # get each financial statement
---> 10     pnl = ticker.financials
     11     bs = ticker.balancesheet
     12     cf = ticker.cashflow
KeyError: 'regularMarketOpen'
```

I also tried to solve this problem as in [Yfinance KeyError: 'regularMarketOpen'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726968/yfinance-keyerror-regularmarketopen) post but I didn't find raw `"data = utils.get_json(url+'/financials', proxy)"` in yfinance/base.py

Comment: The code in your error (`for ticker in tickers`) is different from the code above `for ticker in fang`

Comment: @QWERTYL yes I was wrong. Now I've updated a code and have an error "regularMarketOpen"